# Uninstall from command-line using installshield

Tags: command-line, installshield, uninstallation

Is there any way of being able to force through an uninstall rather than an upgrade on InstallSheild?

I currently have a Setup.exe and a MSI file
but everyime I attemp the uninstall using the pre-recorded ISS if my install is older than the current version it first upgrades and If I run the same file again then it uninstalls,

now im wondering if there is a way where I could force it to uninsatll --- this is what I have currently

```
...\setup.exe"  /x /s /f1C:\Remove.iss
```

Comment: Apparently this maybe a fix for this problem:

You will need to disable small/minor upgrades to acheive this. 
1. Go to Upgrades View
 2. Click on the Upgrade Windows Installer setup node
 3. In the right pane, select Disable radio button for small/minor upgrade settings. 

This will ensure that OnUpgrade value is set to 0 in setup.ini even when compressed inside setup.exe
**The problem is that I dont want to disable minor upgrades :O**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the setup.exe you've built, why not use the one cached on the machine? Check the Uninstall key for details (like path) and you might still be able to mix in your `/s /f1C:\Remove.iss` if the removal pages are similar enough.

Comment: Yup, That is what I ended up with, I have interigated the registery to find the install by name and then I get `UnIninstallPath` which gives the path to the cached setup.exe and then I run that with my argumnets and `ISS` file. Thanks for your help.